# Need a grep command for this task

Tags: grep

I have a big txt file and I am looking for seq id that starts with species name "ABS". When I do grep "ABS", I only get the list of ABS but not seq id followed by that word. For example list what I am looking for is like this:

```
ABS|contig05671,
ABS|contig04453,
ABS|CL5170Contig1,
ABS|contig02526,
```

But, when I do, grep "ABS" filename.txt, I get the result like this:

```
ABS,
ABS,
ABS,
ABS,
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From `man grep`:

```
Context Line Control
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before  matching lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
          contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line  containing  a
          group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With
          the -o or --only-matching option,  this  has  no  effect  and  a
          warning is given.
```

So if you need the matching line and the following one, you do `grep -A1 ABS file.txt`, and similarly for the preceding line with `-B1`.

However, if you want to format the results in another way (e.g. put the two lines on one and separate by the pipe character) you need a different tool than `grep`. `grep` does searching, whereas you also want editing.

Comment: The OP appears to be asking how to retrieve only the line _with_ the matching text, not that line plus the one before/after.

Comment: @AJMansfield The command that the OP shows does show the lines with the matching text, so I am guessing the "id" is not on the same line with the search string.